# opengv installation not in pip3 list

Tags: python-3.x, pip, computer-vision, python-3.7, python-packaging

I have a question. I followed the http://laurentkneip.github.io/opengv/ 
installation manual. And i did correct the path by using the command

```
cmake ../opengv -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON -DPYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION=3.7 -DPYTHON_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/
```

and I also ran the command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyopengv.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

to bring the built package in the opengv/build/lib to the python3-package.... 
But I really have no idea why!! There is no opengv in the pip3 list???

The final problem was that I can not import pyopengv in openSFM...

But the first problem is I think is because there is no opengv in pip3 list..

[image]